# Low RAM for application in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, swap

I install software in Linux called Spades, but I can't run it because of a RAM problem.

When I tap the "spades.py --test" command, I get this error:

[image: when i tap "spades.py --test" command i have this error]

When I tap the "free" command to check the swap memory, I have this result:

[image: when i tap "free" command to check the memory of swap i have this result]

When I contacted support, Spades sent me this mail, but I still can't solve the problem:

[image: when i contact support spades they send me this mail but i still can't solve the problem]

[here is the result of the command free -h and as you can see the memory swap is totally shared that's why it is no longer free!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NjzJ.png)[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NjzJ.png)

Comment: The letter from Spades support confirms the problem: you don't have enough RAM for this application.  If you want to run it, buy more RAM.  If you haven't added more RAM, that explains why you still can't solve the problem.  What can people here do to solve the problem for you?  (We're not going to buy you more RAM.)

Comment: You can try running `free -h` to show how much memory you have in a human readable format. As fixer1234 said, you don't have enough memory to run the application. So you need to add more memory, or find another application that doesn't need as much memory.

Comment: thank you guys, but the question now is why the swap memory I have is totally shared, normally it should not be shared. Sorry if you find that my questions are naive, I'm still beginner ...

Comment: There isn't really "swap memory".  You have a swap partition on your hard drive that augments RAM.  You could probably benefit from a bigger swap partition (4-8 GB swap partition for 4 GB RAM if there is space to enlarge the partition).  That gives the system space to shuffle memory content that isn't immediately needed, to free up RAM for what it needs now.  That's very beneficial is you are doing several concurrent things and switching back and forth between them.  Some big applications load things like tools when you need them, and can benefit.  (cont'd)

Comment: But if an app needs a certain amount of space to do a task, there are limits to how helpful swap can be.  To some extent it can continuously shuffle active bits and pieces so it's like using more virtual RAM, but the process is very slow.  So even if it works, the performance can be abysmal.